# Click a Link To Update 2 iFrames and 1 Div

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, onclick

My code currently uses javascript to update 3 separate iframes on my website page when a link is clicked. This works fine. But, now I have an issue with needing one of the iframes to update with Google Adsense code. And, if you have ever worked with incorporating Adsense into a site, you know that it can't be loaded into an iframe, because it's against policy.

You also can't ever hide the adsense code on the page using "display: none," etc. It has to render on the page, as used.

So, what I'm looking to do is alter my code so that clicking the link updates two iframes just like before, but change the third update command to instead update a div on the page, where the Adsense code will go.

However, again, the Adsense code can't be hidden on the page to be revealed by the click, and it can't be loaded in a frame.

Can you think of a way to do this? I'm wondering if maybe I could put the Adsense code in a text file perhaps, and then call it in to the DIV somehow from there?

I'm sure this could be done in php, and the Adsense code pulled from a database. But, I was hoping to not have to go that route.

Any suggestions on how to have one link update 2 iframes, and a div using javascript, css, jquery, ajax, etc?

I have searched for a solution, but am coming up empty so far.

HTML:

LINK:

```
<a href="javascript:loadThree('https://www.example.com/page1.htm','https://www.example.com/page2.htm','https://www.example.com/page3.htm')">
```

IFRAMES:

```
<iframe name="iframe1" src="" width="932" height="600" align="left" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe name="iframe2" src="" width="932" height="600" align="left" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe name="iframe3" src="" width="932" height="600" align="left" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script language="javascript">
function loadThree(iframe1URL, iframe2URL, iframe3URL)
{parent.iframe1.location.href=iframe1URL
parent.iframe2.location.href=iframe2URL
parent.iframe3.location.href=iframe3URL}
</script>
```

Comment: Is the URL of the one you want to load in the div in the same origin (https(s), domain, port [if any])? Then you can easily use ajax to do it. Look at jQuery's `load` function. Otherwise, you're going to run into CORS issues and it gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: Hello Heretic, thanks for responding! Yes, everything will be on the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<body>
    <h1 style="display:flex;
        justify-content:center;color:green;">
        GeeksforGeeks
    </h1>
  
    <iframe src="about:blank" id="frame1">        </iframe>
    <iframe src="about:blank" id="frame2">           </iframe>
    <button id="update">Click me</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('update').addEventListener('click', function () {
              // Change src attribute of iframes at a same time
            document.getElementById('frame1').src ='https://www.google.com/search?q=java&igu=1';
            document.getElementById('frame2').src ='https://www.google.com/search?q=farming&igu=1';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <iframe id="f1"></iframe>
  <iframe id="f2"></iframe>
  <p><span onclick="SetPage('Farm', 'Fish')">Farm and Fish</span></p>
  <p><span onclick="SetPage('Man', 'God')">Man and God</span></p>
  <p><span onclick="SetPage('Sea', 'River')">Sea and River</span></p>
  <p><span onclick="SetPage('Auto', 'Manual')">Auto and Manual</span></p>

   <script>
       function SetPage(url1,url2)
       {
          document.getElementById("f1").setAttribute("src", 'https://www.google.com/search?igu=1&q=' + url1);
          document.getElementById("f2").setAttribute("src", 'https://www.google.com/search?igu=1&q=' + url2);
       }   
   </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```